# What is a jambu tree?

Tags: history, india

I am reading 'The Wonder That Was India' by A.L.Basham. In chapter 1, Introduction the author mentions as a footnote that,

> The ancient Indians knew their sub-continent as *Jambudvipa* (the continent of the *jambu* tree).

What was/is the *jambu* tree, if it is mentioned in any Hindu scriptures and do we still find it in India?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to HSE. We here discuss about Hinduism scriptures but not history of India. If you want to know whether the hindu scriptures has references to Jambu tree then this is the place to ask. But if you are asking about history of a tree used to/still available in India, then this is not the place to ask. Please edit your post accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: There are plenty of Jambu trees in my home town.

Comment: BTW there is a cosmic significance of the word Jambudvipa.

Comment: @Mr_Green I just edited it. Thanks.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto will need a little more than that.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto sure everything in the universe has a cosmic significance to it.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jambudv%C4%ABpa): "The word Jambudvīpa literally refers to "the land of Jambu trees" where jambu (also known as jamun) is the Indian Blackberry ([Syzygium cumini](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syzygium_cumini)) and dvīpa has two meanings "island" or "continent" and "planets" situated in the ocean of outer space." [Sanskrit dictionary](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=jambu&lang=sans&action=Search) says it's the Rose Apple tree ([Syzygium jambos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syzygium_jambos)).

Comment: @sv. I don’t find jamun trees all over India.

Comment: Why do you expect a tree to be found all over a country?

Comment: @sv. Why else was the land called jambudvipa ?

Comment: So according to you, a national bird, animal or tree has to found in every village, town, and city to be called 'national'...?!

Comment: @sv. Hey, it’s called Hindustan because Hindus are found in majority. It’s called Bharata because a great King Bharata once ruled the land. It’s called Aryavarta because Aryans lived here. Similarly jambudvipa should means that at one point jambu trees were found at most places to have titled it so. Now a national bird or animal is like an insignia like most rulers used animal or plant motifs before governments.

Comment: 'it’s called Hindustan because Hindus are found in majority' - not really, look up the [etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindustan#Etymology). 'It’s called Bharata because a great King Bharata once ruled the land.' - the whole land or part of the land?

Comment: Maybe at that time these trees were in abundant. Sv's comment should answer your question. If not, then please make the question clear.

Comment: My question stands clear. If you’re having trouble answering it then please give up. Now would be the best time. I have clearly mentioned the source from where I picked my question. However, if Wikipedia had answered it for me, I wouldn’t have asked it here. Also this question didn’t show up as previously asked on this site. Kindly, excuse me and thank you for engaging.

Comment: @Noeshel There should be something in Markandeya Purana. I'll check and post an answer. Meanwhile you can join chatroom here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism for related discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Jambudvipa and the related Jambu tree have been mentioned in various Puranas. The Jambu tree is nothing but the rose apple tree.

Here are a few references from the Devi Bhagavatam which mention about the tree and the Dvipa (that is named after it):

> Thus the seven oceans had their origins. And the portion of the earth,
>   that was included within the ruts, became the seven islands (Dvîpas).
>   0 Child! Now hear about the seven Dvîpas and the seven Oceans :-- The
>   first is the Jambu Dvîpa; the second is Plaksa, the third is S'almalî;
>   the fourth is the Kus'a Dvîpa; the fifth is Krauncha; the sixth is the
>   S'aka Dvîpa; and the seventh is the Puskara Dvîpa. The second Dvîpa
>   Plaksa is twice the first Jambu Dvîpa and so on; each succeeding Dvîpa
>   is twice as large as its previous one. Now hear the names of the
>   oceans.
>
> **Devi Bhagavatam Book 8; Chapter 4**

> 1-31. S'rî Nârâyana said :-- O Child Nârada! Now hear in detail about
>   the divisions of the earth into the Dvîpas and the Varsas as marked
>   out by the Devas. In brief, I describe about them; no one can speak
>   about this in details. First, the Jambu Dvîpa is one lâkh Yoyanas in
>   its dimensions. This Jambu Dvîpa is round like a lotus. There are nine
>   Varsas in it and excepting the Bhadrâs'va and Ketumâla, each is nine
>   thousand Yoyanas in its dimensions (i. e., in its diameter or
>   circumference?) and there are eight very lofty mountains, in those
>   Varsas, forming their boundaries. Of the Varsas, the two Varsas that
>   are situated in the North and South, are of the size of a bow
>   (segmental); and the four others are elongated in their size. The
>   centre of all these Varsas is named Îlâvrita Varsa and its size is
>   rectangular. In the centre of this Îlâvarsa is situated the golden
>   Sumeru Mountain, the King of all the mountains, one lakh Yoyanas high.
>   It forms the pericarp of the lotus earth.

> 1-37. Nârâyana said :-- The Jambudvîpa has been described, how it is
>   and what is its width. It is surrounded on all sides by the salt
>   ocean. As Meru is surrounded by Jambudvîpa, so the salt ocean is
>   surrounded by Plaksadvîpa, twice its size. As the ditch is surrounded
>   by gardens, so the salt ocean is surrounded by gardens. **As the Jambu
>   tree exists in Jambudvîpa,** so the Plaksa tree exists in the Plaksa
>   Dvîpa and of the same size. The name Plaksa Dvîpa is derived from the
>   name of this Plaksa tree. This tree is of a golden colour. Fire exists
>   at its bottom with form incarnate. This is, named Saptajihva.
>
> **Devi Bhagavatam Book 8; Chapter 12**

The translator (Swami Vijnanananda) identifies Jambu to be rose apple.

> The World Mother becomes very much pleased when one offers to Her the
>   following things :-- Gur, honey, ghee, milk, curd, Takra, apûpa, fresh
>   butter, Karkatî, Kusmânda, Modaka, Panasa, plantain, **Jambu
>   (rose-apple)**, mangoe, sesamum, oranges, Dâdima, (pomegranate) Vadarî
>   (Jujube) the Dhâtrî (Âmalaki) fruit, Pâyasa, Prithuka, gram, cocoanut,
>   Jambîra. Kaseru, and S’ûrana.

Comment: I am a little confused here. Firstly, according to the book Jambudvipa is one of the seven islands (continents?) and then it later adds that it is surrounded on all sides by salt water. 
Is it talking of the continents or world as one big dvipa divided into seven smaller dvipas?


Also, if you could name the present names of the dvipas to make it easy to remember.

Comment: Yes, according to Puranas, the Jambudvipa is surrounded by the Lavana Samudra (salt ocean). Well, Jambudvipa is divided into 9 parts (called as Varsas), of which Bharat Varsha is the southernmost part. Now, this Bharat Varsha is further sub-divided into nine parts of which the 9th one can be taken to be the present day India. Even Srilanka is part of Jambudvipa, it is mentioned in the Purana as one of the Upa-Dvipas of Jambudvipa.

Comment: @Noeshel Since world maps have changed so much from those ancient times, we can't give exact present names of these Dvipas. You can read a bit more about the topic from here: https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/jambudvipa

Comment: okay. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Noeshel No problem ..